How to manage work based on diverging Linux kernel release branches
My team is working to bring Linux to our platform. We based our work on a release branch from our silicon vendor (pretend this branch is called acme-linux-5.10). I've been asked to port our work over to the new upstream release branch, acme-linux-5.15. Sounds simple, but the history from acme-linux-5.10 to the HEAD of my team's branch is impossible to grok. We have merged branches from other vendor trees to get hardware support, backported patches from upstream, and cherry-picked commits from god-knows-where to get where we are today. We've been working from this release branch for multiple years. I can't filter the history by author, because one of the chief contributors to our product has a long history contributing to other products before this one.
Playing with git cherry, I've been able to narrow down a set of 430 commits that I can try to individually cherry-pick onto acme-linux-5.15, but this sounds terribly unsafe and like a great way to lose my marbles, especially since that has me applying commits that were previously introduced via a merge commit directly onto our history. The other thing I have thought to do is start with cherry-picking the history of critical device tree and driver source files, and then investigate any compilation errors and runtime bugs from there.
tl;dr: I'm trying to migrate a long and complicated git history from one Linux kernel release branch to another and trying to keep my sanity in the process.
My question is general: How do other folks maintaining Linux support for specific platforms solve this problem? Should we have done something differently to maintain better hygiene of our working branches?

You answered to your Q in the very first paragraph: We have merged branches from other vendor trees to get hardware support, backported patches from upstream, and cherry-picked commits from god-knows-where to get where we are today. Your process is broken from day 1. People don't know how to utilise Git in the best ways when the project is not under their control. So, the solution is to always do rebase on the downstream branches, while keeping track of the upstream. That way you will always have a clean base. Now you should invest man-months if not man-years to go through the mess.

When you are about to make a release, tag that. You will always have a possibility to branch out from the tag in the future if needed. So, TL;DR: git rebase for downstream master / main branch, git tag for the local releases. That's how we do in our company. Weekly based on vanilla rcX. The departments who are working with the repo send PRs to our internal tree and they have got merged (and re-merged) altogether.

Now, how I would solve your case. First of all, I would try to rebase to the latest LTS vanilla for the given release (let's say v5.10.y), assuming that acme follows the process I described above (if they don't, you are doomed). This will drops the backported patches over the time to LTS releases. Do the same with v5.15 (it's also LTS, hence I assume acme knows what they are doing). Then, when you have your initial tree being rebased, start analysing one-by-one the changes from the oldest to newst and forward port them. This is a lot of work even for a team, for you it may takes years.

All that said, good luck!

I may be teaching a grandmother to suck eggs, but I'd start by creating two branches of the current HEAD. One as a backup to remember where you were, and one as a rebase branch. Then try and rebase the rebase branch onto acme-linux-5.10, and hopefully end up with a nice, linear patch series on top of acme-linux-5.10. Then try and rebase a copy of that onto acme-linux-5.15.

Thank you both! It seems like the vendor's hygiene is no better. A git merge-base tells me they haven't rebased since Greg KH cut the v5.10 tag. As much as I want to rebase onto mainline's release branch, maybe introducing vendor changes with a merge commit, it sounds like my best bet is just to make sure I have a linear patch series on top of the vendor's release branch, and continue to rebase on top as they add commits.
